# Fitting gaussian to data in python

Tags: python, gaussian

Hi I'm new to programming and for the life of me I can't seem to figure out how to fit a gaussian to my data. This is what I currently have. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
from numpy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = loadtxt("/home/*****")

t,q = data[:,2], data[:,3]                         
t,q = loadtxt("/home/*****", usecols = (2,3), unpack=True)

plt.scatter(t,q, marker='.', s=20)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Do you want to plot a histogram instead of a scatter plot?

Comment: This question has been asked again and answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/23156522/2062965

Answer (score 0):

You currrently draw a scatter plot. The [docs](http://matplotlib.org/examples/api/histogram_demo.html) have a demo for plotting a histogram, which might be Gaussian, depending on the distribution of your data.
You need something like

```
plt.hist(x, 50, normed=1, histtype='stepfilled')
```

There are further demos [here](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/histogram_demo_extended.html)

Comment: But wouldn't it need to be a 2D histogram to account for the two columns of the array?

Comment: @boson I wasn't clear what you wanted to do from the question

Answer (score 0):

You could look at [astropy.modeling](http://astropy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modeling/). An example of gaussian fitting from their website:

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.modeling import models, fitting

# Generate fake data
np.random.seed(0)
x = np.linspace(-5., 5., 200)
y = 3 * np.exp(-0.5 * (x - 1.3)**2 / 0.8**2)
y += np.random.normal(0., 0.2, x.shape)

# Fit the data using a box model
t_init = models.Trapezoid1D(amplitude=1., x_0=0., width=1., slope=0.5)
fit_t = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
t = fit_t(t_init, x, y)

# Fit the data using a Gaussian
g_init = models.Gaussian1D(amplitude=1., mean=0, stddev=1.)
fit_g = fitting.LevMarLSQFitter()
g = fit_g(g_init, x, y)

# Plot the data with the best-fit model
plt.figure(figsize=(8,5))
plt.plot(x, y, 'ko')
plt.plot(x, t(x), 'b-', lw=2, label='Trapezoid')
plt.plot(x, g(x), 'r-', lw=2, label='Gaussian')
plt.xlabel('Position')
plt.ylabel('Flux')
plt.legend(loc=2)
```