# Fitting Gaussian curve to data in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, optimization, gaussian

I'm trying to fit and plot a Gaussian curve to some given data. This is what I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Generate data
mu, sigma = 0, 0.1
y, xe  = np.histogram(np.random.normal(mu, sigma, 1000))
x = .5 * (xe[:-1] + xe[1:])

def gauss (x, y):
    p = [x0, y0, sigma]
    return p[0] * np.exp(-(x-p[1])**2 / (2 * p[2]**2))

p0 = [1., 1., 1.]

fit = curve_fit(gauss, x, y, p0=p0)
plt.plot(gauss(x, y))
plt.show()
```

When I run the code I get this error:

```
TypeError: gauss() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

I don't understand where I have given my function 4 arguments. I'm also not convinced I'm using the curve function correctly, but I'm not sure exactly what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

## Edit

Here's the Traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "F:\Numerical methods\rw893  final assignment.py", line 21, in <module>
    fitE, fitI = curve_fit(gauss, x, y, p0=p0)
  File "F:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 515, in curve_fit
    res = leastsq(func, p0, args=args, full_output=1, **kw)
  File "F:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 354, in leastsq
    shape, dtype = _check_func('leastsq', 'func', func, x0, args, n)
  File "F:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 17, in _check_func
    res = atleast_1d(thefunc(*((x0[:numinputs],) + args)))
  File "F:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 427, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata
TypeError: gauss() takes exactly 2 arguments (4 given)
```

Comment: Could you provide the full traceback? This will show *where* `gauss` is being called with four arguments.

Comment: There's a lot of it..

Comment: The last line of the Traceback is this:
  File "F:\Portable Python 2.7.5.1\App\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py", line 427, in _general_function
    return function(xdata, *params) - ydata

Comment: Edit your question to include all of it - just paste it in and click `{}` to format it as code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your callback is called in `curve_fit` with a different number of parameters.
Have a look at the [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html) where it says:

> The model function, f(x, ...). It must take the independent variable
>   as the first argument and the parameters to fit as separate remaining
>   arguments.

To make sure this works out you might want to take `*args` after the first argument and have a look at what you get.

Comment: So my Gaussian function should contain four parameters?

Comment: I am not familiar with this function specially, but that seems to be the number of arguments that you get. You might want to have a look at what parameters you get and make sense from that.

Comment: Well the parameters I want to fit are x0, y0 and sigma, which I have combined as p. Adding p into the curve_fit bracket results in the program telling me p is not defined.

Comment: That's because there is no `p` defined outside of you model function. Have a look at the example in the documentation and try to adjust your `gauss` function.

Answer (score 3):

Check the first scipy documentation [docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html):

> **scipy.optimize.curve_fit**
>
> scipy.optimize.curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0=None, sigma=None, **kw)
>
> ```
> Use non-linear least squares to fit a function, f, to data.
>
> Assumes ydata = f(xdata, *params) + eps
> ```

## Explaining the idea

The function to be fitted should take **only scalars** (**not**: `*p0`).
I want to remind you that you hand over the initialization parameters `x0`, `y0`, `sigma` to the function `gauss` during the call of `curve_fit`.
You call the initialization `p0 = [x0, y0, sigma]`.

The function `gauss` returns the value `y = y0 * np.exp(-((x - x0) / sigma)**2)`.
Therefore the input values need to be `x`, `x0`, `y0`, `sigma`.
The first parameter `x` is the data you know together with the result of the function `y`. The later three parameters will be fitted - you hand over them as initialization parameters.

## Working example

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

# Create data:
x0, sigma = 0, 0.1
y, xe  = np.histogram(np.random.normal(x0, sigma, 1000))
x = .5 * (xe[:-1] + xe[1:])

# Function to be fitted
def gauss(x, x0, y0, sigma):
    p = [x0, y0, sigma]
    return p[1]* np.exp(-((x-p[0])/p[2])**2)

# Initialization parameters
p0 = [1., 1., 1.]
# Fit the data with the function
fit, tmp = curve_fit(gauss, x, y, p0=p0)

# Plot the results
plt.title('Fit parameters:\n x0=%.2e y0=%.2e sigma=%.2e' % (fit[0], fit[1], fit[2]))
# Data
plt.plot(x, y, 'r--')
# Fitted function
x_fine = np.linspace(xe[0], xe[-1], 100)
plt.plot(x_fine, gauss(x_fine, fit[0], fit[1], fit[2]), 'b-')
plt.savefig('Gaussian_fit.png')
plt.show()
```

[image: Result from the fit is shown in the plot.]

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import loadtxt
import numpy as np
from scipy import *
from matplotlib import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def func(x, a, b, c, d, x0):
    return a*np.exp(-(x-x0)**2/(2*d**2)) + c

x = np.linspace(0,4,50)
y = func(x, 2.5, 1.3, 0.5, 1.0, 2.0)
yn = y + 0.2*np.random.normal(size=len(x))

p = [1,1,1,1,1]

popt, pcov = curve_fit(func, x, yn, p0=p)


plt.plot(x,func(x,popt[0],popt[1],popt[2],popt[3],popt[4]))
plt.plot(x,yn,'r+')
plt.show()
```

This should help. This can also be extended to a 3d Gaussian, then the
input array 'x' should be a k-dimensional array for the (x,y) values and 
'yn' should be the z-values.

Comment: Thanks for this. Sorry if this is obvious but could you tell me what the yn part of the code is for? Also what do popt and pcov represent?

Comment: 'y' is the real Gaussian. 'yn' is just the gaussian with some random noise over it. 'popt' is the array with optimum values. 'pcov' is the coveriance per optimum value. Also see: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html